# Qml, SQLite and the EstimatedSize parameter

Tags: qt, sqlite, qml, qtquick2

QML has a module called `LocalStorage`.
It exposes the function `openDatabaseSync` which accepts several parameters.
One of them is the `EstimatedSize` (in bytes) of the db (as stated by the QML documentation).

I'm currently working on a desktop application and I cannot figure out which is the estimated size of the db, for it will grow and grow up in time for sure.

What will it happen once the actual size goes over the estimated size?
Which are the drawbacks of that situation?
Unfortunately, I've not been able to find any details on how this value is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cursory glance at [the source code](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtdeclarative.git/tree/src/imports/localstorage/plugin.cpp) suggests that the `EstimatedSize` parameter isn't used at all. It might only be in there for compatibility with the HTML5 synchronous local storage spec.

Comment: From the Qt Docs:  "description and estimated_size are written to the INI file (described below), but are otherwise currently unused."  [link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-localstorage-qmlmodule.html)